# File not being found on server Apache

Tags: php, macos, apache

I'm simply trying to open a php file I have created and keep getting this.
 The requested URL /~Wade/HelloWorld.php was not found on this server.

I just recently did a reinstall on my Mac. Which shouldn't have affected my .conf files. With that being said, I can still typein localhost in my URL and it returns "It Works" so I know the server is still up? I'm confused

Comment: can you verify that the file is in the location that you believe it to be in?

Comment: did you check the logs at /var/log/apache/* especially the error_log? What's stated there?

Answer (score 0):

*(Note: Assuming you use a recent version of OS X)*

Since a couple of versions (not sure which, but at least since Mavericks), userdir Sites are disabled in the httpd.conf shipped with OS X.

Assuming you know how to edit files owned by root, remove the `#` from these two lines in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
#LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
```

```
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

Next, create a file in `/etc/apache2/users/`. Its name doesn't matter, as long as it ends in `.conf`.
Its contents should be:

```
<Directory "/Users/Wade/Sites">
    Require all granted

    # The next two lines are optional and may bee too lax for
    # production, but I deem them good for a development environment.

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Also, in every httpd.conf that has shipped with OS X for as long as I can remember, PHP has been disabled by default. So you'll also have to remove the `#` from this line in `httpd.conf`:

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

You probably also want to set the `ServerName` directive, to suppress a startup warning.
There's a commented out line somewhere that reads

```
#ServerName www.example.com:80
```

Either change it (and remove the `#`), or just add a new one after it that reads

```
ServerName 127.0.0.1:80
```

If you want your server to be accessible from other devices in your local network, replace `127.0.0.1` with `0.0.0.0`, and if you use a different post, adjust accordingly.

After that, run `sudo apachectl -k restart` to restart Apache and you should be good to go.